# Is there a way to check a particular stored procedure name in the TFS with MS VS?

Tags: tfs

I have this TFS server setup in the MS Visual Studio. There's a stored procedure name given, for assumption the name is `MyStoredProcedure`. I don't know where this stored procedure is in the TFS or who made a check-in in this. I know the branch in which I have to look for, but not sure how to find it because there are a lot of components.

Let me know if the question needs to be more understandable.

I've tried the Ctrl+F option with the stored procedure name in the "view history" tab of that branch, but was unable to find it. Maybe its not even there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

You can check in a single stored procedure into VSTS with VS.

Just go to the project and select the schema like dbo and go to folder stored procedure.

Add a new file, select file type as stored procedure.

After creating the file, paste your stored procedure code there, built the project and check in.